# Angular - Make section of string variable bold

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there any way in which I can make part of a string being assigned to a variable bold?

I have tried the following:

```
boldTxt = 'bold'

message = 'this text should be ' + this.boldTxt.toUpperCase().bold() ;
```

But what I get in the HTML is:

`this should be <b>BOLD</b>`

[**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bold-test)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML`, something like:

`<p [innerHTML]="message"></p>`

Setting the value of **innerHTML** removes all the element's contents and replaces them with nodes constructed by parsing the 
HTML set in the **message** variable.
When the text is set using statement `<p>{{message}}</p>` the content is not parsed as HTML but as plain string.